# How to include Material Design libraries without npm

Tags: javascript, css, material-design

How to use Material UI in simple html page without installing it using npm ?

is there a way I can use material UI like bootstrap, like including a css library and/or a javascript library and start using sample codes like these http://material-ui.com/#/components/buttons

Comment: I second this. I am new to React and I was trying to material-ui to build something. It seems like the only way to use it is to first learn how to use npm, browserify, gulp and all of that first. I am sure it is better for a production system, but it would be really helpful if there was a way to just include a script tag and get going

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)

Here is an example CDN for Bootstrap3 based ui :

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/css/material-wfont.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/css/material-wfont.min.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/css/material.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/css/material.min.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/css/ripples.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/css/ripples.min.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/fonts/Material-Design-Icons.eot
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/fonts/Material-Design-Icons.svg
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/fonts/Material-Design-Icons.ttf
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/fonts/Material-Design-Icons.woff
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/js/material.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/js/material.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/js/ripples.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.6/js/ripples.min.js
```

Comment: I am not sure this is the corect answer. The guy is asking about Material UI, a react.js library. Not about bootstrap material design.

Comment: Well, the question was not tagged with "React" tag, so i had an assumption that the author wanted simple material "look and feel" and gave the react library as an example of the material ui components. Not sure what would count as a "correct" answer in this case, but seems it has solved authors problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following CDN url.

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/sam-g-steel/bbb0bd62238db76025bc6e2a3e9d576f/raw/32f8e0a099d463b73d214ffdd77d2b4bc5e53026/material-ui-react.min.js
```

Check this http://codepen.io/meprasobh/pen/MpvKRE

Answer (score 0):

According to https://material.io/develop/web/getting-started, it looks like you need to include these files:

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
```